# How to Integrate skype chat on website

Tags: javascript, html, skype

I am building new website in this website client required 24/7 live customer support. i want to integrate skype chat on website chat interface should be on website on client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it by placing a Skype button on your site.
http://www.skype.com/intl/en/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/

Comment: Is it possible to integrate skype's video calling functionality?